# VB and .NET not always running

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB.NET application (engineering based, uses numerical input) that is used by many clients. Nearly all the time it runs correctly but on some clients PCs it throws unpredictable errors. For example it crashed saying data were missing but the data had been entered, it just hadn't been processed by the app. I know this is a 'how long is a piece of string' question, but can anyone suggest where I might start looking?
It is compiled for NET 4.0

Comment: The problem is that I can never replicate the problem, which leads me to think it might have something to do with the PC concerned. E.g. memory or the way NET 4.0 works on it.

Answer (score 3):

For an intermittent bug like this, you need to do one of two things:

1. Find a predictable and reproducible way to force the same crash that doesn't involve, "Oh, just let it run for a while. One of these files will crash it."

or

2. Add a bunch of logging to the app, so you can trace back when and why a crash occurred. Ultimately, the purpose here is to provide the information you need in order to accomplish #1.

We won't be able to help you much until you can reproduce the crash on demand in your own environment. Usually at this point the steps you need to take to fix the problem become readily apparent.